# Can I define fields on an implicit many-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

Here's a version of my models.py file. I've removed irrelevant fields and the model names are made up, for security reasons:

```
class FilmStudio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)


class ProductionCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    film_studio = models.ForeignKey(FilmStudio)

    class Meta:
        # Ensure that a given combination of ProductionCompany name and FilmStudio object is unique
        unique_together = ('name', 'film_studio')


class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    production_company = models.ForeignKey(ProductionCompany)


class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    films = models.ManyToManyField(Film, blank=True)
```

Although it is not explicitly defined, there is a many-to-many relationship between an `Actor` and a `FilmStudio`. This is evidenced by the following call to the Python API:

```
FilmStudio.objects.filter(productioncompany__film__actor__name='Samuel L. Jackson').distinct()
```

This returns all of the `FilmStudio` objects which Samuel L. Jackson is related to, and each one only once. What I'd like is to define extra fields on the relationship between an `Actor` and a `FilmStudio` (it doesn't work too well in this example, I know, but it makes sense for my scenario).

Following what is described in [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), I could use an intermediate model to define extra fields on the relationship between a `Film` and an `Actor`, for instance.

But this doesn't seem to help me with my problem. I don't want to define the `Actor` to `FilmStudio` relationship explicitly, since it's an existing relationship based on other relationships.

Is it possible to define fields on the relationship that I'm describing?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. In this made-up code, ProductionCompany.name and Film.title *are* the extra fields on the relationship between FilmStudio and Actor. I think you might need a more concrete example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see what you mean. The extra fields that I'm referring to include information only relevant to a `FilmStudio` to `Actor` relationship, regardless of any Film or ProductionCompany. So, the relationship can be accessed through the Film and ProductionCompany models but the data I want to add does not concern them. Defining a separate relationship would allow me to add the data, but then require me to manually specify the relationship, which would be tedious and redundant.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you are not able to do that.

The reason for that is that it is nowhere to store the extra fields of that relationship. If I understand you correctly, these "extra fields" are not implicit in the actor-film or productionstudio-film relationships, so even though you say they are implicit, the extra fields themselves are explicit.

You could try to emulate it by creating an explicit direct relationship whenever it is needed. Then you could simulate the extra fields using the model as an abstraction, but I am not sure if this is what you want. If you opt for this kind of solution you can use default values (in your abstraction) for filling in relationships that don't have a instance yet.

Does that explanation make sense to you?

EDIT:
(I have not double checked that the code works, so be vary)
OK, so you have the original models:

```
class FilmStudio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)


class ProductionCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    film_studio = models.ForeignKey(FilmStudio)

    class Meta:
        # Ensure that a given combination of ProductionCompany name and FilmStudio object is unique
        unique_together = ('name', 'film_studio')


class Film(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    production_company = models.ForeignKey(ProductionCompany)


class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    films = models.ManyToManyField(Film, blank=True)

# The "solution" would be:

class ActorProductionComapny(models.Model):
    production_company = models.ForeignKey(ProductionCompany, related_name='actors')
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, related_name='companies')
    # your extra fields here
    someproperty = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        # let's say one per actor
        unique_together = ('production_company', 'actor')
```

This is going to get messy really quickly

We use a [F object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) like this:

```
FilmStudio.objects.filter(productioncompany__film__actor__name='Samuel L. Jackson', 
                          productioncompany__film__actor=F('actors__actor'),
                          actors__someproperty="Plays poker with CEO").distinct()
```

The tricky part is going to be handling default values (i.e. when there is no value) This would have to be implemented using a [custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/), but then I am out of my depth.

I will try to explain as well as I can, but it's going to be tricky.

If you want to make a filter on the relationship you may have to do something like this:

```
def filter_prod(pq_query, someproperty, actor_name):
if someproperty == "Default":
    # Great, this means we can ignore the parallel relationship:
    return pq_query.filter(productioncompany__film__actor__name=actor_name)
else:
    # Here comes the hard part
    FilmStudio.objects.filter(productioncompany__film__actor__name=actor_name, 
                              productioncompany__film__actor=F('actors__actor'),
                              actors__someproperty=someproperty).distinct()
```

The thing I am trying to illustrate here is that there are two kinds of actor-productioncompany relationships, those with custom field values (non-default), and those without.

Now, you can make a custom getter that looks something like this:

```
class ProductionCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    film_studio = models.ForeignKey(FilmStudio)

    def get_actors(self):
        # This one is not lazy, so be aware
        actors = list(self.actors)
        # Get a list of actor IDs
        actor_ids = [a.actor_id for a in actors]
        for actor in Actor.objects.filter(films__production_company_id=self.id):
            if actor.id not in actor_ids:
                actors.append(ActorProductionComapny(actor=actor, production_company=self)
                actor_ids.append(actor.id)
        return actors

    class Meta:
        # Ensure that a given combination of ProductionCompany name and FilmStudio object is unique
        unique_together = ('name', 'film_studio')
```

This should not save the relationship to the database until you call `.save()` on an instance. You can also add a custom save method that ignores/aports `.save()` calls where all the values are default. Just remember to check if it is a new instance or not, because you don't want it to cancel a "set back to default" call. You could also make it delete on a "set back to default", but check if you are allowed to do that within `.save()`.

For even more complex queries (mix of default and non-default) you have Q-objects (further down on the page from F objects)

Comment: You're right, the 'extra fields' are not related to anything in the Film or ProductionStudio models. What I meant was implicit was the relationship itself - using the Actor-Film and ProductionStudio-Film relationships, we can form a relationship between Actor and FilmStudio. The data I want to add, though - that needs to be explicitly defined for a given Actor-FilmStudio relationship. Could you perhaps provide a code example for your proposed solution? I'm not sure if I follow it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to create an extra model to store this extra relational data between `Actor` and `FilmStudio`.

```
class Actor(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     films = models.ManyToManyField(Film, blank=True)
     film_studios = models.ManyToMany(FilmStudio, through='ActorFilmStudio')

class ActorFilmStudio(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor)
    film_studio = models.ForeignKey(FilmStudio)

    # define extra data fields here
    data1 = models.TextField()
    data2 = models.IntegerField()
```

One way to think about this: the data you're trying to store belongs to an Actor-FilmStudio relation, and is not related in anyway to `Film` or `ProductionCompany`.

Your existing ability to retrieve the a set of `Actors` for a given `FilmStudio` (or vice-versa) does not necessarily imply you can store relational data belonging to these two models using the models defined in your example.

Keep in mind that each of the models you defined in your example are backed by a table in your database. In the case of Actor.films field, Django creates an extra table to store the many-to-many relationship data.

Since you're looking to store relational data between Actor and FilmStudio, you need to consider where the data will be stored in your database. Can you store the data in the `Film` model? or the `ProductionCompany` model?

Comment: Yeah - the question of where in the database this data will be stored is a good one. Like you said, Django creates tables for many-to-many relationships (like my actor_films table which stores the relations between Actors and Films) so I suppose I was hoping that it could do something like that here. The data could feasibly be stored in the ProductionCompany model (it would make sense) but I'm not sure how that would work. Perhaps the only realistic solution is to do something similar to your code - create a new model to store the relationship and populate it where extra data is desired.